# Find the next date based on Interval (month/quaterly)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE @Temp(
    Date datetime,
    Flag bit)

@Temp table as data from 01-04-2019  to  31-04-2020  (366 records) and flag=0

DECLARE startdate date='12-04-2019', interval  int  =1 OR 3
```

Expected Result: If interval is 1 month, based on startdate, flag to be updated as 1 below records and rest for 0

```
    date         flag
    01-04-2019    0
    .             0
    .             0
    12-05-2019    1
    .             0
    .             0  
    12-06-2019    1
    .             0
    .             0
    12-07-2019    1
    ..            0
    31-04-2020    0
```

If interval is 3 month, flag to be updated as 1 for quarter

```
      date        flag
    01-04-2019    0
    .             0
    .             0
    12-07-2019    1
    .             0
    .             0  
    12-10-2019    1
    .             0
    .             0
    12-01-2020    1
    .             0
    31-04-2020    0
```

I am stuck trying get the result. I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me awhile to realize that your dates were in different format than I'm used to.

I would go with a common table expression as opposed to a cursor.  Besides that, consider the month difference between any given date and the start date.  Take the modulo of that difference (that's what the '%' symbol is).  If it's 0, then your interval has been hit and so activate your flag.

```
declare 
    @startdate date = '04.01.2019',
    @interval int = 3; -- or 1, or whatever

with

    dates as (

        select      @startdate dt, 1 flag

        union all
        select      ap.nextDt, 

                    flag = 
                        case
                        when day(ap.nextDt) <> day(@startdate) then 0 
                        when (month(ap.nextDt) - month(@startdate)) % @interval = 0 then 1
                        else 0 
                        end

        from        dates
        cross apply (select nextDt = dateadd(day,1,dt)) ap
        where       dt <= dateadd(year,1,@startdate)

    )

    select    *           
    from      dates 
    option    (maxrecursion 367)
```

Comment: if  i give startdate date as  '31.01.2019' ,  in feb  month  ther is no 31  so is  it possible to  set  flag for month end date i.e 29th  and same for April month is 30 th & soon..

Comment: Making a flag out of it in your situation will have some complexities.  Like, if you enter '28.01.2019', '29.01.2019', '30.01.2019', or '31.01.2019', is your program supposed to pick up on the fact that it should output the last day of february?  Sounds like you're going to put in a lot of work for this requirement.  Is it worth it?  In general, you can find the month end date via `eomonth` or `dateadd(day, -1, firstdayofnextmonth)`.  If you do decide to attempt to implement this flag and get stuck and then ask another question (showing what you've tried).  It's too much for the comments.